# Screen resolution detection

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, screen, resolution

I know that similar questions were asked but this is different.

Intro: i'm triyng to make an website with adaptive designs (3 templates for 3 widths intervals as follows: 1200+px, 600-1200px, 600-px).

Problem: i have a really hard time with user screen width detection. 
I' know that only js can detect user screen size so i tried two ways of detection.
1. First i used a cookie in order to store the width but because cookie becomes active only after refresh i need to refresh the page.
2. Second o used to send width as param with GET but again i need to refresh the page in order to send params.

So the question is: is there a way to get screen size without page refresh (the value to be stored in a cookie/session). I need the proper template to be delivered on first visit of page.

If there is no solution (only with refrest needed) for width detection how can a solve the problem for crawlers so they won't see the redirect.

Comment: Why don't detect and get template files trough javascript instead of php?

Comment: better you should create size free template.

Comment: @Joran: because is a drupal website using php.

Comment: @RotariRadu Drupal also uses html/css/js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here but you should be using @media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
and
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: i know that's the proper way of doing is using media queries however, a layout will only prevent displaying some data, a different template will prevent loading data. That's why i would like to use template instead a layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. Surely css @media queries are the way to do this?

If for some reason you do need the width in Javascript, then you can do

jQuery:

```
$(document).width();
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.clientWidth
```

I would revise your methodology if you can though..?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a DDR (Device Description Repository), exactly this one : http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/
It works good and gives a lot of etails exept on firefox.
No CSS OR JS required for use.